# PHP set object properties dynamically

Tags: php, object, setter

I have a function, that should read array and dynamically set object properties.

```
class A {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function set($array){
        foreach ($array as $key => $value){
            if ( property_exists ( $this , $key ) ){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = new A();
$val = Array( "a" => "this should be set to property", "b" => "and this also");
$a->set($val);
```

Well, obviously it doesn't work, is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

It seems that nothing is wrong with this code, the question should be closed

Comment: Remove brackets {} and will work! -> `$this->$key = $value;`

Comment: Well, this obviously is working ..., just tested on php 5.4

Comment: This is working: http://codepad.org/KlQvEcn4

Comment: yea, i just noticed, sorry guys, i made a mistake before setting stuff in the code

Comment: how can i close this thread?

Comment: @Benedictus it will be closed if needs be, you can't close it yourself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php

You can using `Reflection`, I think.

```
<?php 

function set(array $array) {
  $refl = new ReflectionClass($this);

  foreach ($array as $propertyToSet => $value) {
    $property = $refl->getProperty($propertyToSet);

    if ($property instanceof ReflectionProperty) {
      $property->setValue($this, $value);
    }
  }
}

$a = new A();

$a->set(
  array(
    'a' => 'foo', 
    'b' => 'bar'
  )
);

var_dump($a);
```

Outputs:

```
object(A)[1]
  public 'a' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  public 'b' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: you can, but why use it if simple setter will do

Comment: Answered, because posted something usefull

Answer (score 50):

You only need to remove brackets {} and will work! -> `$this->$key = $value;`

Answer (score 1):

It is to note that Reflection is not recommended in production mode.
Depending on the context this one liner can do the job:

```
    $object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```