# Creating & setting PHP object properties dynamically using $this keyword

Tags: php, properties, mocking, phpunit, this

I'm trying to dynamically create properties of my test case derivative class inside a `setUp` method, but I'm having a terrible time getting it working.

```
$folder = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes';
foreach ( scandir($folder) as $filename ) {
    $path = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
    if ( is_file( $path ) ) {
        $nameExtSplit = explode('.', $filename);
        $namePrefixSplit = explode('Hf', $nameExtSplit[0]);
        $propertyName = 'Mock'.$namePrefixSplit[1];
        // $propertyName is getting set correctly—I've checked
        $this->{$propertyName} = $this->makeMock($nameExtSplit[0]);
    }
}
```

I've tried `$this->$propertyName`, `$this->{$propertyName}`, and `$this[$propertyName]`, all to no avail.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336747/php-set-object-properties-dynamically), but he's dynamically *setting* properties instead of creating *and* setting them.

How can I dynamically create properties within the object?

**EDIT:** More details:

This code is inside a class that extends the PHPUnit TestCase class and from which all my test classes are derived. I'm trying to autoload a mock for each one of my classes into protected properties of my custom TestCase class. I'm trying to make it so I don't need to edit my TestCase to have a mock available for a newly created class.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that `$this->makeMock($nameExtSplit[0])` is what's failing, not the actual assignment to `$this->{$propertyName}`?

Answer (score 1):

Use overloading:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

You'll have an array property for your data, and use the __set(), __get(), __isset(), and __unset() magic methods.

Example 1 should be exactly what you're trying to do. Add those methods to your class.

You also might be able to call the __set method directly

```
$this->__set($propertyName, $this->makeMock($nameExtSplit[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP 5.4 or higher?
Try setting the var with something static. If that works, try puting the output of the method in a temporary variable first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
$this->propertyName;
```

The variable `$propertyName` should somewhere be declared as one of the following three:

1. `public $propertyName;` (can be used even outside the class)
2. `private $propertyName;` (can only be used in the same class)
3. `protected $propertyName;` (can be used in the same class and a extended class)

in the same class.

Example:

```
<?php
class setUp {
   public $propertyName;

   function folders() {
      $folder = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes';
      foreach ( scandir($folder) as $filename ) {
        $path = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
          if ( is_file( $path ) ) {
            $nameExtSplit = explode('.', $filename);
            $namePrefixSplit = explode('Hf', $nameExtSplit[0]);
            $propertyName = 'Mock'.$namePrefixSplit[1];
            // $propertyName is getting set correctly—I've checked
            $this->propertyName = $this->makeMock($nameExtSplit[0]);
         }
      }   
   }
}
```

**Update**

```
spl_autoload_register(function( $class ) {
    include_once '/classes/'.$class.'.php';
});

$user = new User(); // Will load: /classes/User.php
```

When you call a class it will automically load it.

Comment: This code is meant to autoload mocks from a folder full of classes. Defining property names ahead of time would defeat the purpose. Is there a way I can do this dynamically?

Comment: @NathanArthur I have updated my answer please let me know if that is what you mean. Maybe you can fidle around with it to make it work for you

Comment: Thanks for the example autoloader, but no, that's not what I'm trying to do. I'll edit my question with more details.

Comment: Details added to question.