# How to do dynamic setmethod data to entity?

Tags: php

I would like set many JSON data for object, but I wouldn't like write lot of set method. Example:

```
//(POST : JSON DATA) JSON keys equals entity variable names
{
"data1": "banana",
"data2": "index, follow",
"data3": "true",
"data4": "abcdef",
"data5": "false",
"big_data1": "lorem ipsum ...."
"name": "apple"
  ....
}
```

My entity (short version)

```
class Category
{
 //....
 private $data1;

 public setData1(string $data1): self{
  $this->data1 = $data1;
  return $this;
 }
 public getData1():string{ return $this->data1; }

 //...
}
```

My Controller

```
//...
public function index(){
  //post data json to object
  $data = json_decode($postdata); # data object
  $category = new Category(); # new category class

  $object = new \ReflectionObject($category);

  /**
     What is the next step?
     $this->setData1($data->data1);
     $this->setData2($data->data2);
     if(!empty($data->big_data12)
       $this->setBigData12($data->big_data12)
     .
     .
     .
     $this->setData12($data->data12)

  */
}
```

How to do a simple way? How is it avoid possible to writing many set methods?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336747/php-set-object-properties-dynamically ?

Comment: Okay this not wrong solution, but I would like pairing properties with associated set method. I want not use $property->setAccessible(true); and not use reflection in Entity class.

Comment: Then the only way is to use the magic method `__set`, there is an answer answered below taking that path. You can also overload `__isset` and `__unset` to achieve all functionalities you might require that gives you also ability to do pairing. Maybe you can add method `setMany` in the `Category` class that will accept array and perform set for each element in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use reflection at all.  You can use magic methods. Specifically, `_call()`. [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

A very simple, naive implementation:

```
class Category
{
    private $data1;
    private $data2;
    private $data3;
    private $bigData12;

    public function __call($method, array $arguments)
    {
        $verb = substr($method, 0, 3);
        $noun = lcfirst(substr($method, 3));

        if (!property_exists($this, $noun)) {
            throw new Exception('Property does not exist');
        }

        switch($verb) {
            case 'set':
                $this->$noun = $arguments[0];
                return $this;

            case 'get':
                return $this->$noun;
        }
    }

}

$cat = new Category();
$cat->setData1('hello')
    ->setData2('hola')
    ->setData3(12345)
    ->setBigData12('hello world');

echo $cat->getData1(), "\n";
echo $cat->getData2(), "\n";
echo $cat->getData3(), "\n";
echo $cat->getBigData12(), "\n";
```

You can see it working [here](https://3v4l.org/V7WM5).

Note that I wouldn't recommend doing this too much. This kind of thing is very error prone, can't be type-hinted, and the gains are from minuscule to non-existent.